# Отправка изображения на сервер

Tags: c++, qt

Написал клиент/сервер, хочу отправить серверу изображение.
Оно приходит, но только открыть его невозможно: пишет, что повреждено. 
Использую Qt.

**Код клиента(отправитель):**

```
if (fileName != "")
    {
       QMessageBox::information(0, "", "Hello");
       QByteArray arrayForSend;
       QDataStream streamForSendFile(&arrayForSend, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
       streamForSendFile.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_4);
       QFile myFileForSendServer(fileName);
       myFileForSendServer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

      while (!myFileForSendServer.atEnd())
      {
         // QMessageBox::information(0, "", "Hello");

   QByteArray tempBlockForSendServer = myFileForSendServer.read(sizeof(qint64(1024)));
          QByteArray blockForSendServer;
          QDataStream streamForSendFile_2(&blockForSendServer, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

          qDebug() << tempBlockForSendServer.size();
          streamForSendFile_2 << qint64(0);
          streamForSendFile_2 << tempBlockForSendServer;

          streamForSendFile_2.device()->seek(0);
          mySocket->write(blockForSendServer);
      }

        myFileForSendServer.close();
    }
```

**Сервер:**

```
QDataStream streamForFile(mySocket);
        streamForFile.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_4);

        QFile file("MyFile.jpg");
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

        if(!sizeBlock)
        {
            if (mySocket->bytesAvailable() < (unsigned int)sizeof(quint64))
            {
                return;
            }
            streamForFile >> sizeBlock;
        }

        if (mySocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeBlock)
        {
            return;
        }

        char ch_sizeBlock[1024];
        while (!streamForFile.atEnd())
        {
            int iBlockSize = streamForFile.device()->read(ch_sizeBlock, sizeof(ch_sizeBlock));

            file.write(ch_sizeBlock, iBlockSize);
        }
    file.close();
```

Comment: И что делать дальше??

Comment: Какой протокол используете? При сравнении файлов нужно найти места в которых побился принятый файл. Если в начале или в конце то возможно вы буфер сокета неправильно пишите. Если в середине, то это сетевые пакеты теряются/бъются, в этом случае надо повышать устойчивость протокола к помехам.

Comment: Протокол TCP/IP.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При передаче и чтении файла проверьте буфера на количество байтов, надежнее было бы передавать на сервер размер файла, а затем сам файл и читать пока не прочитается весь файл. Как по мне удобнее работать с отдельным сокетами для обмена данными один для чтения второй на запись.

Запись

```
QFileInfo fileInfo(fileName);
QFile file(QDir::toNativeSeparators(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath()));
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    return false;
}
//
//
int bytesRead=0;
qint64 sendSize=0;
char *buffer=new char[bufferSize];
bool isFinishedFlag=true;
int packetNumber=0;

while (sendSize!=fileInfo.size())
{
    bytesRead=file.read(buffer,bufferSize);
    sendSize+=bytesRead;

    if (bytesRead==-1)
    {
        isFinishedFlag=false;
        break;
    }

    QByteArray data;
    QDataStream dataStream(&data,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    dataStream<<(quint32)0;
    dataStream<<packetNumber;
    dataStream.writeBytes(buffer,bytesRead);
    dataStream.device()->seek(0);
    dataStream<<(quint32)(data.size()-sizeof(quint32));

    socketWrite.write(data);
    emit bytesRemoteWritten(data.size());

    int recievePacketNumber=-1;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if (TcpFunctions::ReadInt(&socketWrite, timeOutRead, recievePacketNumber)) break;
        else
        {
            socketWrite.write(data);
        }
    }

    if (recievePacketNumber==-1)
    {
        isFinishedFlag=false;
        break;
    }

    packetNumber++;
}
//
file.close();
delete buffer;
return isFinishedFlag;
```

Чтение на сервер:

```
bool isFinishedFlag=true;
qint64 downloadSize=0;
long lastPacketNumber=-1;
bool flagStart=true;

QFile file(QDir::toNativeSeparators(fileName));
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    return false;
}

while (downloadSize!=size)
{

    if (!flagStart)
    {
        bool isReadyRead=false;
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            if (!socketRead.waitForReadyRead(timeOutRead))
            {
                if (lastPacketNumber!=-1)
                {
                    TcpFunctions::WriteInt(&socketRead, lastPacketNumber);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isReadyRead=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isReadyRead)  isFinishedFlag=false;
    }
    else
        flagStart=false;

    while (socketRead.bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint32))
    {
        if (!socketRead.waitForReadyRead(timeOutRead))
        {
            isFinishedFlag=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    quint32 blockSize;
    QDataStream dataStreamIn(&socketRead);
    dataStreamIn.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_7);
    dataStreamIn >> blockSize;
    while (socketRead.bytesAvailable() < blockSize)
    {
        if (!socketRead.waitForReadyRead(timeOutRead))
        {
            isFinishedFlag=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    int packetNumber=0;
    QByteArray data;
    dataStreamIn>>packetNumber;
    dataStreamIn>>data;

    if(packetNumber!=lastPacketNumber)
    {
        file.write(data);
        emit bytesRemoteWritten(data.size());
        downloadSize+=data.size();
        lastPacketNumber=packetNumber;
    }

    if (lastPacketNumber!=-1)
    {
        TcpFunctions::WriteInt(&socketRead, lastPacketNumber);
    }
}
file.close();
return isFinishedFlag;
```

Там можна отследить потери при передачи.